# Is QtAudioEngine available for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: sound, application-development, qt, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I'm trying to add sound to a Qt application on Ubuntu 16.04 with the Ubuntu SDK. The following QML builds but fails at run-time with `module "QtAudioEngine" is not installed`:

```
    import QtQuick 2.2
    import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
    import QtMultimedia 5.6
    import QtAudioEngine 1.1  // <-- nope
```

I see from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466115/qt-audio-engine-not-in-ubuntu-sdk) that `qtdeclarative5-qtaudioengine-plugin` was available for Ubuntu 14.04. I can't find it for Ubuntu 16.04. Do I need to build it?

Answer (score 1):

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51567

So, I'd say that QtMultimedia packages for Debian/Ubuntu were built without that support.

Quote:

> I got it to work by building QtMultimedia with CONFIG+=config_openal and setting the build environment variables INCLUDE and LIB to the openAL includes and libs folders respectively. Note that the windows installer of OpenAL doesn't have an "AL" folder as expected by the build so I renamed "includes" to "AL" and pointed INCLUDE to the parent folder.
>   I manually copied the resulting qml plugin, the qmldir and the plugins.qmltypes to the qt installation's qml folder. Now the audio engine example works.
>
> But I agree, you shouldn't have to go to these lengths to enable features - and +1 to documenting how to do this.